# Cube rooting a negative number does not work?

Tags: google-sheets

I tried using this formula for cube rooting but it doesn't seem to work.

```
=ROUND(C38^(1/3))
```

The value of `C38` is `-2`.

I'm getting the following error:

> Imaginary numbers are not supported in real sheets.

Shouldn't cube roots logically work without being imaginary, whether it's negative or positive?

Comment: Could you share the spreadsheet with us? Or another spreadsheet demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why it's not supported but you can bypass it this way:

`=ROUND(IF(C38 < 0,-1*ABS(C38)^(1/3),C38^(1/3)))`

That would be your formula for rounding a cube root.

Comment: Wow it actually works thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following notation to perform these types of calculations.

### Formula

```
=minus(a^(b/c))
```

### Research

I thought it was a rather odd behavior of Google Spreadsheets and therefore I started to investigate the situation.

It started by performing the calculation in the [Google Calculator](https://www.google.com/search?q=-2%5E%281/3%29#q=-2%5E%281/3%29):
[image]

There, the notation

```
-2^(1/3)
```

was re-written to

```
-(2^(1/3))
```

This solves your problem immediately. Entering the last formula (with `ROUND()`) in Google Spreadsheets, will give you : -1. But why?

### Why

In the first reference, Dr. Math is explaining the matter in detail. Bottom line is that the calculation is returning an imaginary number, like the cube root of -1.

To avoid these calculations, the minus is simply extracted from the calculation and "added" afterwards.

### References

1. [Dr. Math](https://web.archive.org/web/20180114135902/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/62979.html)
2. [There's no bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12810788/1536038)